# Haystack and Elasticsearch: Limit number of results

Tags: django, elasticsearch, pagination, django-haystack

I have 2 servers with Haystack:

- **Server1**: This has elasticsearch installed
- **Server2**: This doesn't have elasticsearch, the queries are made to **Server1**

My issue is about pagination when I make queries from **Server2** to **Server1**:

- **Server2** makes query to **Server1**
- **Server1** send all the results back to **Server2**
- **Server2** makes the pagination

But this is not optimal, if the query return 10.000 objects, the query will be slow.

I know that you can send to elasticsearch some values in the query (**size**, **from** and **to**) but I don't know if this is possible using **Haystack**, I've checked documentation and googled it and found nothing.

- How could I configure the query in **Haystack** to receive the results 10 by 10 ?

## Edit

- Is possible that if I make `SearchQuerySet()[10000:10010]` it will only ask for this 10 items ?
- Or it will ask for all the items and then filter them ?

## Edit2

I found this on Haystack Docs:

- [SearchQuery API - set_limits](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchquery_api.html#set-limits)

it seems a function to do whatt I'm trying to do:

> Restricts the query by altering either the start, end or both offsets.

And then I tried to do:

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet

sqs = SearchQuerySet()
sqs.query.set_limits(low=0, high=4)
sqs.filter(content='anything')
```

*The result is the full list, like I never add the set_limit line*

- Why is not working ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haystack works kinda different from Django ORM. After limiting the queryset, you should call get_results() in order to get limited results. This is actually smart, because it avoids multiple requests from Elastic.

Example:

```
# Assume you have 800 records.
sqs = SearchQuerySet()
sqs.query.set_limits(low=0, high=4)
len(sqs)  # Will return 800 records
len(sqs.get_results())  # Will return first 4 records.
```

Hope that it helps.

Comment: I have to try this, I fought with the code a lot back then, and didn't find info to achieve it. Thanks !!

Comment: I get this error - `AttributeError: 'SearchQuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_results'`

Comment: last line should be `len(sqs.query.get_results())`

Answer (score -1):

Adding on to the Yigit answer, if you want to have these offsets on filtered records just add filter condition when you form the `SearchQuerySet`.

Also remember once the limits are set you can't change them by setting them again. You would need to form the `SearchQuerySet()` again, or there is a method to clear the limits.

```
results = SearchQuerySet().filter(content="keyword")
#we have a filtered resultSet now let's find specific records
results.query.set_limits(0,4)
return results.query.get_results()
```